# Retrieving Menu in Explorer

Tags: c++, winapi, contextmenu, explorer

As the context menu for the desktop and explorer windows is disabled, I wanted to make a little something to bring back some functionality. My idea was to just list out things in a context menu (copy, paste, new, open with, etc) whenever a user right-clicks one of these windows, and then just simulate the appropriate event in the actual menu (file->new, edit->copy, etc). It wouldn't look perfectly pretty, but it would hopefully allow for the use of right-clicking.

The problem is that I cannot seem to get the actual menu. I opened My Documents and tried going down the child list towards `SysListView32`, calling `GetMenuItemCount` each time. Most returned -1, and the only other return value than that was 0.

How am I supposed to get a handle to the (file, edit, view...) menu?
If this isn't possible, is there a way I could simulate the user clicking something on the normal context menu, even if it's disabled?

Also, is there a way of making this work for the desktop? You can get the same type of thing if you view it in the explorer window, so I figured there might be a way.

I'm running Windows XP and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier not to disable the real menus in the first place?

Comment: Uhh, it's actually the school board disabling them. My argument is that it was pointless to disable them in the first place. Funny story though, I actually did have the power to enable them (and do anything else  you can think of) not too long ago though (I told them). I'm just trying to make it easier to work. It's annoying doing things like file>edit-ing files that are on the desktop.

Comment: Can you open the desktop in an explorer window and circumvent it that way? Is it just your desktop that you are banned from using?

Comment: The right click does not work on the desktop, nor on any explorer windows such as `My Documents` or the desktop in a window. It's a group policy; other applications handle right clicks normally.

Comment: As for your question, you are on the wrong track. `GetMenuItemCount` needs an `HMENU`  but you've been feeding it `HWND`. That won't work. It also won't work from a different process. You could possibly write a program that use the shell COM APIs to show a context menu for a shell item. But your basic problem is the bone-headed group policy. You really need to get that fixed. Tell the IT guy that takes the decision that I said he was a fool and was stopping you doing any useful work.  ;-)

Comment: I apologize; I didn't word my procedure correctly. I pass the `HWND` along to `GetMenu`, which seems to work on every window except for explorer. And believe me, my opinion is worth nothing. I, along with a friend, did someone's job for them for 10 years' worth, saving the board time and money while increasing their security (adding some actually) and didn't even get a thank you. The IT person of our school is not open to any suggestions at all either.

Comment: To elaborate on my previous success, I've been able to ungrey menu items in random applications and simulate the pressing of one (most namely the `scientific` mode of Windows Calculator when it starts, as it doesn't by default).

Comment: Thanks for the Shell COM hint. I found out there's an example in the Platform SDK, so I'm reading through that at the moment.

Comment: Well, I almost have something I found working. It seems to succeed up to the point where I call `IcontextMenu::InvokeCommand`, but that's more of a separate problem. If you post an answer of the Shell COM API, I'll gladly accept it. I also found `MN_GETHMENU`, but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: You could try one of the many apps that invoke the shell menu directly to see if they work (Agent Ransack, WinDirStat, amongst others.

Comment: Actually, I got the `InvokeCommand` working. That pretty much solves this portion of the problem :) For a specific file, the menu came up and I was able to click commands whenever I right clicked my own window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per David Heffernan's comment,

```
As for your question, you are on the wrong track. 
GetMenuItemCount needs an HMENU but you've been feeding it HWND. 
That won't work. It also won't work from a different process. 
You could possibly write a program that use the shell COM APIs 
to show a context menu for a shell item. But your basic problem 
is the bone-headed group policy. You really need to get that fixed. 
Tell the IT guy that takes the decision that I said he was a fool 
and was stopping you doing any useful work. ;-)
```

This led me onto the path of using the correct alternative method to achieve my goal.